# How to reverse a door's opening direction

Tags: doors, door-frame

I found [a previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14093/flip-a-door-frame) which is similar to this. However, that person was asking about having the door open outward in the opposite direction. I had initially thought about doing as much, but realized that at some point or another, someone was going to get a facefull of door if I did so.

So, I want the door to continue to open inward, but swing left to right instead of right to left. I'm somewhat limited in the questions I can answer because said door is about 2 hours away, so I can't say if it's on hung hinges or whatever. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swapping a door's left/right swing direction involves moving the hinges to the opposite side and then moving the door pull/latch/lock to the side where the hinges used to be. Doing this ends up creating a need to patch up all the old hinge mount locations (both in door and on jamb) and the holes left by the door knob and lock set.

It is possible to do all this and make the result look fresh if the door and jamb will be painted. It can be very tedious cutting, fitting and gluing in wooden inserts for the holes and old hinge insets. If it is a stained or naturally finished door where the wood grain shows it would be close to impossible to make the door and frame look decent and unpatched. If it is a steel jacketed door expect the patching job to be more difficult.

My recommendation, to minimize the labor involved, is to purchase a new door and jamb and install it with the door swing direction that you want. This will result in the ability to finish the door to the way you want without all the patching work.

Comment: As was pointed out in the answer to my question, there are ways to make this work with an unpainted door if you're willing to reverse the door's inside and outside, plus losing a bit of the door's width and modifying the frame to make up for that... but it's a bigger job than it appears at first glance.

Comment: If this is exterior door and both sides can tolerate the elements putting inside to out side can work door then does not need patched but jamb bolt holes and hinge mortise will need patched then bore and mortise the opposite jambs accordingly

Comment: @pam Door may still need to be altered to reverse the closing edge's bevel, and to extend the hinge mortises across the edge of the door. See the related question for details.

Comment: @Pam it's a bathroom door. Some...person decided it would be best to have it open directly into a glass shower stall. How the stall hasn't broken, I do not know. The door can't even open entirely. It drives me crazy.

Comment: @michael Karas this could be done. We will be renovating the entire house, so a little extra patching and paint isn't going to require any more work on our end really.

Comment: @broklynite what if anything might it swing into if it swings into bath the other way? If nothing then the door can be flipped inside to outside as I mentioned

Comment: If it swings in right to left (as it is now) it hits the shower stall. Swinging in left to right it hits nothing. If it swings out, it can easily whack someone walking by unexpectedly. That's why I wanted to know about reversing it so it opens left to right- sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: http://www.houselogic.com/home-advice/windows-doors/door-handing/.  Check here for good tios

Comment: @broklynite the link in above comment may help

Comment: Much obliged Pam!

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the door 180°. You'll end up with an upsidedown door, but it will open the other way.

[image: door]
<sup>*Original*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*Rotated*</sup>

Obviously the jamb will have to be altered, and the handle will be at a strange height.

Comment: Sometimes photoshop can be used for evil. I wouldn't downvote your answer for this, but every fiber in my being shudders at the idea of a panel door being spun. (A slab might not be quite as terrible...)

Comment: Hm. Might be doable.